# Реализовать функцию вычисления с использованием циклов

Tags: c++, функции

Необходимо реализовать функцию с использованием цикла на С++.

Есть вот такой вариант исполнения (вход и выход сходятся), но исходя из темы задания, нужно использовать цикл.

Помогите преобразовать, пожалуйста, чтобы был задействован цикл.

```
#include <iostream>                              
#include <math.h>               
using namespace std;

double S(double N, int x)
{
    if (N < 0) return sqrt(x + 1);
    return sqrt(x + N * static_cast<int>(S(static_cast<int>(N - 1), x)));
}

int main() {
    cout << S(2, 2) << endl;
    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << S(1.5, 3) << endl;
}
```

[image: Задание]

Comment: `Само уравнение ввело в ступор` Распишите поподробнее, в чём суть проблемы, что конкретно вызывает трудности?

Comment: Математическая составляющая. Мы же ищем S, но без этой самой S уравнение не решить, т.к. она в середине функции. И где здесь поместить цикл тоже не совсем ясно...

Comment: 1) `N` и `x` вам даны. 2) Сперва найдите `S(0, x)`. Формула дана. 3) Зная `S(0, x)`, вы сможете найти `S(1, x)` (оно зависит от `S(0,x)`). 4) Зная `S(1, x)`, вы сможете найти `S(2, x)`. 4) Продолжайте процесс до тех пор пока не доберётесь до `S(N,x)`.

Comment: Я бы сделал [примерно так](https://ideone.com/f6CAkQ).

Comment: Спасибо! Благодаря Вам тоже пришла в похожему коду. Очень сильно помогли!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Окончательный вариант стал таким.

```
#include <math.h>               
using namespace std;

double calculate(double x, unsigned n) {
    double res = sqrt(x + 1);
    for (unsigned i(1); i <= n; ++i)
        res = sqrt(x + i * floor(res));
    return res;
}

int main() {
    cout << fixed;
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << calculate(2, 2) << "\n";
    cout << calculate(1.5, 3) << "\n";
    cout << calculate(0, 0) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```